# Rails option_for_select how to show a combination of two-fields of hash in drop-down

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, form-for

`rails 6.1`, `ruby 3.1.1`

On a form (`form_for`) I have a drop-down select box using `options_for_select` in my `:sort_order` field.  It takes a hash and is currently showing colors as the options text, which is not very intuitive to the user. I could switch it around and show the numbers as the select text, but that still might not be super helpful to the user. I want to combine the key/val in the hash items and show that in the option text.

```
<% sort_hash = {'platinum' => 1, 'diamond' => 2, 'gold' => 3, 'silver' => 4, 'bronze' => 5} %>

<tr>
  <td>Sort Order:</td>
  <td>
    <%= f.select(:sort_order, options_for_select(sort_hash), :prompt => "Select a Number") %>
  </td>
</tr>

# this produces:
<select name="living_muay_thai_badge[sort_order]" id="living_muay_thai_badge_sort_order"><option value="">Select a Sort Order</option>
<option value="1">platinum</option>
<option value="2">diamond</option>
<option value="3">gold</option>
<option value="4">silver</option>
<option value="5">bronze</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is have it show the `key: value` together in the option text like this:

```
<select name="living_muay_thai_badge[sort_order]" id="living_muay_thai_badge_sort_order"><option value="">Select a Sort Order</option>
<option value="1">1: platinum</option>
<option value="2">2: diamond</option>
<option value="3">3: gold</option>
<option value="4">4:silver</option>
<option value="5">5: bronze</option>
</select>
```

I haven't found any threads online that show how to do this with my hash in the `options_for_select`, and anything I try doesn't work.  I can rework the hash if that makes this easier.

Help?

Thanks in advance.